# How to read external USB hard drive formatted ext3 from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, nas, ext3

I had to format a USB hard drive to ext3 to use it with a Linksys nas box.  Now I can't read the hd when I unplug it from the nas and plug it directly into my Windows 7 computer.  (The computer accesses the nas over a wireless connection, so I like to plug the hd directly into my pc when transferring large files.)

How can I leave the hd formatted with ext3 and yet be able to access it (read/write) when I plug it directly into my pc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Ext2 IFS for Windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/), which may require a bit of tweaking on 7. Another option is to use [Cooperative Linux](http://www.colinux.org/) within Windows itself to access the volumes.

Comment: Thanks, John.  I tried but couldn't get ext-ifs to install on my W7.  On first glance, it looks like Co-op Linux means basicially installing Linux on my pc.  If that's true, I think I'll hold off and hope for an option with less overhead.

Comment: Check out this article for getting Ext2IFS running on 7: http://www.networkedmediatank.com/showthread.php?tid=23220  you may be interested in Ext2FSD alternatively: http://www.ext2fsd.com/

Comment: Note that Ext2 IFS can only read an ext2/3 file system if: A. it was removed safely from the Limux machine, B. the node size is 128 bit. To check this, download "mountdiag.exe" and run: "mountdiag.exe <drive-letter>:". http://www.fs-driver.org/download/mountdiag.exe

Answer (score 5):

EXT2FSD works great for me on Windows 7 X64. http://www.ext2fsd.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [Total Commander](http://ghisler.com) with [DiskInternals](http://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm) Reader Plugin! Easy and powerful! (Note: Read only access)

1. Install Total Commander
2. Download the DiskInternals zip and unzip to a directory
3. Install the file system plugin:

   a. Unzip the plugin to a directory of your choice.

   b. In Totalcmd, choose Configuration - Options - Operation - Plugins

   c. Click on "Configure" for .WDX
   [image]

   d. Click Add and choose the .wfx file of that plugin and click OK
4. Enter the usb and on Total Commander navigate to Network Neighborhood
   [image]
5. Select [DiskInternals reader] and then navigate to the directory you need to read/copy/extract
   [image]

Comment: Just good to know: Read-only access

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Diskinternals Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/), which is free software.

However, it provides read-only access.