# Accessing a ReiserFS partition from Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ext3

I checked the couple other [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ext3+windows) on this topic, but the solutions provided are not working in my setup.

## EDIT

- Just found out tonight the partition I thought was ext3 is actually ReiserFS
- The ext3 tools are probably wonderful - but this is a different issue

## /EDIT

### Configuration:

- Windows 7 x64 laptop with an i5 and 4GB RAM
- 500GB hard drive formatted ext3 *attached via USB*

### Current "solution":

- VMware Workstation running Ubuntu 10.10
- pass-through USB connection to VM
- transfer files from the ext3 partition to a FAT thumb drive (also on pass-through USB connection)

### Problems:

- it's **NUTTY** slow (`iostat` shows MB r/w per second under 1, often under .5)
- the thumb drive is only 32GB, so multiple passes are needed to move/copy data

### Tools tried:

- Disk Internals Linux Reader (http://www.diskinternals.com/files/Linux_Reader.exe)

  - doesn't show USB drives
- Explore2fs (http://www.chrysocome.net/downloads/explore2fs-1.08beta9.zip)

  - shows the drive twice, won't mount either image (the actual partition or the "used-space 'drive'"
- Ext2IFS (http://www.fs-driver.org/download/Ext2IFS_1_11a.exe)

  - won't run on Windows 7

### Solution hoped-for:

- some tool (free or inexpensive being the best!) to mount the USB-housed harddrive with the ext3 partition on it natively in Windows 7

#### Alternative not yet tried:

- setting-up Samba on the VM and network-sharing the pass-through-connected drive back to Windows (seems the kludgiest)

What might I be missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read external USB hard drive formatted ext3 from Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/103661/how-to-read-external-usb-hard-drive-formatted-ext3-from-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I've adopted (because I realized it's not ext3 - it's reiserfs):

Using WinSCP to copy from the VM with the pass-through USB drive.

Once I get this drive cleaned-off, it'll be getting a nice reformat :)

Answer (score 4):

I am using [Ext2FSD](http://www.ext2fsd.com) which is freeware. Works great for both reading and writing.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) with [ext2fs](http://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm) plugin (it works with ext3, yes).

Comment: I tried this and the Ext2FSD solution suggested by another answer and found this solution to be slightly better, because it does not require the installation of a driver and also no reboots. Otherwise, both solutions worked well for me on Win7 64bit.